# SQLiteDateBase How create table?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

to delete table I am using

`db.delete(tableName,null,null);`

How can I do to create a table? I don't want use a query in text plain like:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE blabla ();");
```

Comment: There are many tutorials available on this. Did you try searching them?

Comment: Why don't you want to user db.execSQL()?

Comment: There are no convenience methods for creating or dropping tables in the Android SQLite API. `delete()` deletes rows, not tables.

Comment: You should give a try to any of the ORM implementations working on android: ORMLite http://ormlite.com/, GreenDAO http://greendao-orm.com/, ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this for example

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TODO = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_TODO + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TODO
        + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUS + " INTEGER," + KEY_CREATED_AT
        + " DATETIME" + ")";
```

then call

```
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TODO);
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex...  Why even bother with string concatenation?